# Getting random verbiage while printing array variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, java-8

I'm learning basics of `Java` and there seems to be an observation I'm not able to get my head around.

Below is the code that is supposed to print the *binary implementation* of a `base10` number. There are no errors or warnings but logical anomalies I'm looking for answers.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main
{
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        int remainder, quotient, i=0;
        int[] binary=new int[n];

        /* Binary division -Extracting the 1's and 0's out of the base10 number and storing it in binary[] */
        while(n!=0){
            remainder=n%2;
            quotient=n/2;
            binary[i]=remainder;
            n=quotient;
            i++;
        }

        int k=i; // For storing the length of array till I want my bits to be reversed since all other bits are initialized to 0.

        /*Reversing the binary[] to get the coreect binary value.*/
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
            int temp=binary[j];
            binary[j]=binary[i];
            binary[i]=temp;
            i--;
        }

        /*Printing out all the bits of binary number. */
        for(int l=1;l<=k;l++){
            System.out.print(binary[l]);
        }

        System.out.println(binary); /*Prints a garbage looking value: For ex- for 25 i get: [I@33909752 */
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**Concerns for my code:**

**1.** I am not able to comprehend possible reasoning as to why I am getting random garbage looking verbiage when I try to print the array variable - `binary`. Is this something expected? If so what is this?

*For example:*

In my code when I provide an input of `25` I get `[I@33909752` while printing the `binary` variable. I expected something like an `[1,1,0,0,1,0,....,0]`

**2.** I get an extra `0` in front of my binary value if I start my `for-loop` to print the `binary` from `0` instead of `1`

*For example:*

```
for(int l=1;l<=k;l++)
{
  System.out.print(binary[l]);
}
```

Prints `11001` for `25` but if I start the loop from `0`, I get `011001`. I checked all other places of the code by putting SOPLn statements and nowhere the `0` index of array is getting 0. I wonder why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't import arbitrary stuff coming into you mind. You don't use anything from the packages `java.io`, `java.math`, `java.security`, `java.text`, `java.util.concurrent`, or `java.util.regex`. The only thing needing an import in your code so far is `java.util.Scanner`
2. You don't need a construct like `scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?")`. If you are going to read another token, which does not happen in you code anyway, the scanner will already skip white-space, including line breaks, by default. There's also `scanner.nextLine()`, but you don't need it here.
3. Do not close `System.in`. While a `Scanner` created around a resource allocated by yourself should be closed, you are not responsible for `System.in`.
4. `System.out.println(Object)` prints the result of calling `toString()` on the object. For classes not providing an implementation, like arrays, [the method inherited from `java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) produces `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. The `int[]` array's class name is `[I`, that's why you see `[I@` plus some hex number.

   Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(binary));` instead. But this will print the entire array, including the unused elements.
5. Instead of modifying an existing variable in a loop, creating the need for a new variable in the outer scope, you should introduce a new changeable, temporary variable in the loop. Further, you have to become familiar with the standard loop idiom, start at index zero and exclude the end index (use `<` rather than `<=`).

   The loop variable will contain the excluded end index after the loop, when the condition evaluated to `false`. This logic also applies to your first `while` loop; afterwards, `i` will contain the first unused the index or the used length, both interpretations are valid. Subsequent uses must exclude it, using `<`, which is, as said, the usual pattern. For your reversal loop, this also implies that the end index must be decremented before being used.

   Fixing the loop logic will fix your issue with the leading zero.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int remainder, quotient, i=0;
        int[] binary=new int[n];
        /* Binary division -Extracting the 1's and 0's
           out of the base10 number and storing it in binary[] */
        while(n!=0) {
            remainder=n%2;
            quotient=n/2;
            binary[i]=remainder;
            n=quotient;
            i++;
        }
        /*Reversing the binary[] to get the correct binary value.*/
        for(int j=0, k=i-1; j<k; j++,k--) {
            int temp=binary[j];
            binary[j]=binary[k];
            binary[k]=temp;
        }
        /*Printing out all the bits of binary number. */
        for(int l=0; l<i; l++) {
            System.out.print(binary[l]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(binary));
    }
}
```

```
25
11001
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: What a stellar answer. To the point and exactly what I needed. On a related note can you comment about ways in which I can make the array size dynamic. I mean there are lots of unused bits in my array and I wonder if we can get rid of them by asking` java` to keep the size of the array to what its needed. I have a python background where a programmer has the liberty to instruct `lists` to be of acceptable size and so I was wondering if we could do something like this in Java?

Comment: Java's arrays are always fixed size, so either, you change from using an array to using a `List`, e.g. `java.util.ArrayList`, or just replace the array with a new one of the right length, i.e. after the `while` loop, use `binary = Arrays.copyOf(binary, i);`. Or you predict the right array size upfront, using `32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)`.